# Expose API routes with Express when deployed on Netlify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, netlify

I've created a site with [create-react-app](/questions/tagged/create-react-app) that I build in `./client/build` and serve with [express](/questions/tagged/express).

Using [express](/questions/tagged/express), I also setup 2 basic API routes that work well in dev (localhost).

### What I do to deploy on [netlify](/questions/tagged/netlify) ?

I build the client with `react-scripts`
Then I manually set the environment to *production* to build locally the server with `webpack`
Finally I push my code to my GitLab repo, and it triggers the deploy automatically.

Used Netlify deploy's settings :

```
Build command:         Not set
Publish directory:     client/build
```

### Issue

When I try to use one of my API routes, I get an error 404 ...

### Project

My project structure is like this :

```
|   package.json
|   server.js
|   webpack.config.js
+---API
|       dbHandler.js
|       routesHandler.js
+---client
|   |   package.json
|   +---src
|   |   |   App.js
|   |   |   ...
|   +---node_modules
|   +---public
|   |       index.html
|   |       manifest.json
|   |       _redirects
|   \---build
|       |   index.html
|       |   manifest.json
|       |   _redirects
|       |   asset-manifest.json
|       |   favicon_rings.ico
|       |   service-worker.js
|       \---static
|           +---media
|           |       ...
|           +---js
|           |       main.1e7ccdbf.js
|           |       main.1e7ccdbf.js.map
|           \---css
|                   main.fc8f2d26.css
|                   main.fc8f2d26.css.map
+---public
|       _redirects
\---bundles
        bundle.js
```

### Code

Extract from `./package.json` :

```
"main": "server.js",
"homepage": "https://custom.netlify.com",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
  "postinstall": "npm run build",
  "start:dev": "nodemon -e js --exec babel-node -- ./server.js"
}
```

`./client/package.json` :

```
"homepage": "https://custom.netlify.com",
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build && cp build/index.html build/404.html",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

`./client/build/_redirects` and `./public/_redirects`:

```
# Redirects from what the browser requests to what we serve
/*  /index.html  200
```

`./server.js` :

```
import webpackDevMiddleware from "webpack-dev-middleware";
import webpackHotMiddleware from "webpack-hot-middleware";
import routesHandler from "./API/routesHandler";
import config from "./webpack.config";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import webpack from "webpack";
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const ExpressServer = express();
const CLI_BUILD_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "client/build");
const HTML_BUNDLE = path.join(CLI_BUILD_DIR, "index.html");
const compiler = webpack(config);
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

ExpressServer.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
ExpressServer.use(bodyParser.json());
ExpressServer.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
if (isDevelopment) {
  ExpressServer.use(
    webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
      publicPath: config.output.publicPath
    })
  );
  ExpressServer.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
} else {
  // Serve static files from the React app
  ExpressServer.use(express.static(CLI_BUILD_DIR));
}

// Define API routes
var router = express.Router();
router.post("/register", routesHandler.register);
router.post("/login", routesHandler.login);
// Put all API endpoints under '/API'
ExpressServer.use("/API", router);
// All other routes will be directed to the main page of user interface
ExpressServer.get("/", (req, res) => res.sendFile(HTML_BUNDLE));
ExpressServer.get("*", (req, res) => res.redirect(301, "/"));

// Start the server
ExpressServer.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on http://localhost:" + port);
});
```

`./webpack.config.js` :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './API/routesHandler.js',
    './API/dbHandler.js',
    './server.js'
  ],
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    'react/addons': 'react',
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': 'react',
    'react/lib/ReactContext': 'react',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundles'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map',
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? undefined : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', './client/build', './API', '.'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /(\.js$|\.jsx$)/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'airbnb'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css$|\.scss$)/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  node: {
    console: false,
    fs: 'empty',
    fsevents: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/fs/)],
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      minimize: true,
      compressor: {
        warnings: false,
      },
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Netlify is for static file hosting - you can't deploy an Express application to it, only your frontend. You'll need to use a different service (such as DigitalOcean or Heroku) for your API hosting. You could potentially then route traffic to that API server via Netlify using [redirects](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/) if you want to use their CDN for response caching.

**Edit:** This is no longer entirely true - Netlify now also has [support for deploying AWS Lambda functions](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/), allowing JavaScript and Go to be run on the server-side.

Comment: Yup, I run the tech support team for Netlify and would have said the same thing.  Specifically you'll probably want to use the proxying form of redirects described in particular in this section of that article:  https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying - this lets your visitors visit a consistent set of URL's but some paths will be served by that backend transparently to them (same SSL connection to Netlify, content by heroku/etc).  We WILL follow Cacne-Control headers you set on that remote service - so choose wisely :)

Comment: @fool: Ah, cheers for the extra info :) and <3 to you all at Netlify, moved my website across a couple of months back and my experiences have been nothing but positive so far!

Comment: @JoeClay It might be worth updating your answer with a reference to Netlify's new Functions feature.

Answer (score 3):

With Netlify's addition of support AWS Lamdba functions earlier this year, this is actually quite possible now. Here are some resources for those who find this question now.

https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/13/how-to-run-express.js-apps-with-netlify-functions/