# CORS on server header

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I am deploying a simple node server and a React app to Netlify. The React App makes an API request to the server, and uses cors via `const cors = require("cors");` in version 2.8.5.

At first I specified the following (server.js)

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: CLIENT_ORIGIN
  })
);
```

which only seems to tell the server "I am using CORS," but does not specifically set any headers or permit any whitelisted websites to access the server. I then set the `CLIENT_ORIGIN` in a .env file in my dev environment, and via the `Build environment variables` on Netlify. I deployed a new built for both the server and front-end, however I must have gotten it wrong somewhere:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://serverUrl.com/example/get' from origin 
'https://react-app-example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access- 
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an 
opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I then tried setting:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://react-app-example.com"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.sendStatus(204);
  }
  next();
});
```

which also did not work. The error message remained the same. The thing that irks me is that I have a similar from from a few months ago which is built very similarly, but stays on heroku. The same methods as described above work without problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have control/access to server side script that handles your request(s)? If so you should place suitable headers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various things I finally arrived at the fact that Netlify does not support Node apps by itself ([without extra tedious config](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/)).

The closest solution can be found [here in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577411/expose-api-routes-with-express-when-deployed-on-netlify) or via another service like Heroku.
The major issue I have with heroku is that when the `dyno` (in my case the server providing API routes) doesn't get called for a while it goes to sleep to save resources, and in turn takes a whole lot longer to respond on the first call. Have not found any other free solution for node/express apps that serve API routes, yet.

UPDATE: Heroku and Netlify don't play along nicely unless you add the following CORS parameters to the backend:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", CLIENT_ORIGIN);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true); <--- this is the only different line I added.
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.sendStatus(204);
  }
  next();
});
```

And then the following to the front end request via fetch:

```
fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/dept/get/`, {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include', <-- this is the most important change
    })
      .then((res) => {...}
```